# Bootstrap navbar with submenu - how to remove the class "disabled" @media width under 768

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have used the "disabled" class to activate link on main menu. But how can i remove the class "disabled" on media width 768? or how to disable "disabled" class function on small screen? (no need link on "Main menu 1" @768)

```js
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeIn(200);
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(600);
            });
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">



  <div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap nav menu</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="https://www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main menu 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Main menu 2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>     
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```

Comment: (note: mouseover dropdown jquery is not working on current fiddle)

Comment: You can use jquery to toggle the disabled class on screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this , you can check with inspect element , when you hover the dropdown the `disable` class will be removed

```
$(function(){
var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
$('ul.nav').on('mouseover','.dropdown',function(){
    if($windowWidth < 768){
        $(this).find('a').removeClass('disabled');
    }
});
});
```

**check with demo**

```js
$(function(){
 var $windowWidth = $(window).width();
 $('ul.nav').on('mouseover','.dropdown',function(){
     if($windowWidth < 768){
                $(this).addClass('open');
         $(this).find('a').removeClass('disabled');
     }
 });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap nav menu</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="https://www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main menu 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Main menu 2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>     
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
 $(".dropdown.a").removeClass("disabled");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use this to remove the class disabled below 768 pixel screen.

```
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $('a.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('disabled');
}
```

```js
if ($(window).width() < 768) {
  $('a.dropdown-toggle').removeClass('disabled');
}
if ($(window).width() > 768) {
            $('ul.nav li.dropdown').hover(function () {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(600).fadeIn(200);
            }, function () {
                $(this).find('.dropdown-menu').stop(true, true).delay(200).fadeOut(600);
            });
        }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css">



  <div class="container">
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Bootstrap nav menu</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="https://www.google.com" class="dropdown-toggle disabled" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Main menu 1<span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">submenu1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">submenu3</a></li>
            
          </ul>
        </li>
         <li class="active"><a href="#">Main menu 2 <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Main menu 3</a></li>
      </ul>     
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
  </div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
```